# Homodyne-inspired graviton detectors using coherent state gravitional waves....impossible?

Tags: quantum-gravity, quantum-optics

The following pop science [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aR77s9RLck&t=910s) discusses the experimental difficulty of measuring "quanta" of gravity. It seems to me that a significant argument involves how it would be difficult to investigate fluctuations of gravity on the plank scale, requiring detection methods that have densities that would collapse as a black hole.

In optics, one way of "seeing" a photon is by interfering it with using homodyne detection to interfere it with a strong signal. The strong signal essentially magnifies the signal, allowing it to be seen by detectors that are much less sensitive than single photon level.

Could such a scheme be used to measure gravitons? For example, if strong gravitational waves can be detected by LIGO, shouldn't a sufficiently strong wave already be measuring the "amplitude" statistics of the graviton? Similar to how a local oscillator (in a balanced homodyne detector) measures the shot noise (amplitude statistics) of the vacuum.

I suppose the issue is that this needs to be a particuarly strong wave signal so be above experimental noise?

Comment: What would act as a gravitational *local oscillator* whose amplitude is at least, say 30 to 50 times that of the signal to be detected?

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box.

Comment: @hyportnex, the already-detected signals at LIGO would serve as a local oscillator, I assume would constitute a coherent source, and it would be the noise on the signal that's the quantum noise of the fluctuating vacuum. The difficulty I suppose would be to create a "balanced beamsplitter" like setup that can provide both field quadratures

Comment: What you are describing is "just" sampling, that is OK too, and since sampling is heterodyning (the homodyne part being the very low frequency portion) the sampler taking the role of an LO. An "analog" LO with a balanced mixer is something else trying to achieve the same with different hardware. If you sample at the rate twice the bandwidth of the baseband signal then you can synthetically create the in-phase and quadrature components with appropriate digital filtering, and this is what most likely LIGO was actually doing, after all the signal is very low frequency.